# Как отредактировать .idb файл?

Tags: c++, база-данных, visual-studio, visual-c++

Есть коммерческое ПО, при каждом запуске оно подключается к файлу базы данных, файл именуется как uchetati.idb. Поступила задача добавить десяток тысяч записей в БД, руками через ПО это сделать нереально, но если как то получить доступ к редактированию данного файла, то можно попробовать. Файл в ОС инициирован как vc++minimum rebuild dependency file, открываю его через MS VS C++ и вижу код в формате hex редактора.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас СУБД Firebird. Подключайтесь с помощью драйвера Firebird

Comment: Сайт http://firebirdsql.org/   Сигнатура (расширение) точно interbase/firebird версию не вижу.

Comment: В папке с программой обнаружил библиотеку gds32.dll ассоциируется как Yaffil SQL Server (EM) Engine

Comment: Скачайте firebird установите. В папке include там либы, есть папка Demo или что-то такое с рабочими примерами доступа к базе.  gds32.dll - клиентская библиотека firebird. В интернете по firebird много информации.

Comment: Буду переваривать, спасибо большое. ПО получается на Delphi написано, а не на MS Visual C++?

Comment: Нет, ответ неопределено. Если вы занимаетесь взломом - то смотрите сигнатуры exe-шника. Делфи оставляет свои сигнатуры классов,  MS Visual C++ - свои. ПО может быть написано на чём угодно. Да, делфи имеет лёгкую встроеную поддержку Interbase/Firebird, какой-то процент программ под неё написан на Delphi.

Comment: Большое спасибо, Вы очень помогли.